# GTK - Don't highlight buttons on select / hover

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

I'm trying to write a kiosk GUI in ruby/gtk on ubuntu. I'm pretty fluent in ruby, but new to writing GUIs and not great with linux.

I'm using a touch screen, and am using our own images for buttons, e.g.

```
button_image = Gtk::Image.new(Gdk::Pixbuff.new "images/button_image.png")
@button = Gtk::Button.new 
@button.add(button_image)
@button.set_relief(Gtk::RELIEF_NONE)
```

My issue is that when the buttons are pressed or remain selected (or hovered over, although this is less relevant with a touch screen), gtk shows fat, square borders around them. Obviously it's applying gtk's prelight / selected / active lighting to the buttons. I've tried changing the button properties in various ways, and also tryied hacking apart my theme, and while I can modify how the highlighting looks, I can't seem to completely get rid of it. Changing the color of the highlight via my theme is easy, but if I remove my setting there's still a default I can't get rid of.

Does anyone know if there's a way to stop it, or possibly make it transparent? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried meddling with the drawing as Federico suggested, but found that the most direct way to address this was instead to use an event box rather than a button. Event boxes accept clicks just like buttons, but don't respond to selecting, hovering, etc. In ruby, the code looks like this:

```
image = Gtk::Image.new("myfile.png")
event_box = Gtk::EventBox.new.add(image)
event_box.visible_window = false
event_box.signal_connect("button_press_event") do
  puts "Clicked."
end
```

Most of this is exactly like a button; the *visible_window* method, obviously, keeps the event box from being visible under the button image.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to use exactly your image for the whole button, instead of putting an image *inside* the normal GtkButton - but still use all the normal behavior of the button.

The easiest way to do this is to just override the drawing.  If you are on gtk2, connect to the "expose-event" signal, do your drawing there, and return true so that the default handler doesn't get run.  If you are on gtk3, connect to the "draw" signal and do the same.

Comment: oh interesting -- haven't gotten that deep in before but I'll try it out, thank you for the suggestion